# i want to add user name in my data base after fill all the requirements ..this error appears

Tags: mysql, plesk

Error: Connection to the database server failed: Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 42, found 39. Created with MySQL 50171, now running 50555. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix it with

```
MYSQL_PWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql_upgrade -uadmin
```